# Being independant from a shell when i execute a script in ssh

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I am connecting to my linux server with ssh on my git bash in windows and just I just execute a script that does a 2 hours operations on mysql. The problem is that the scripts interrupts after 30min because my session get locked and i can't change the configuration of my windows session because i don't have the admin privileges.
How could i just let the server execute my script other than with cron, is there is a better way ? I am just asking.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Run it inside [GNU screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#toc-Overview-1) or [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki).

This allows you to detach and reattach later to a (or even several) running shell sessions.